# Nativescript angular 2 RadListView LoadOnDemand back to previous page not working (evaluating 'child.onLoaded')

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

Hi Currently I am using nativescript-telerik-ui plugin in my {N} project and using RadListView like below

```
<RadListView #myRadListView [items]="posts"
             loadOnDemandMode="Auto" (loadMoreDataRequested)="onLoadMoreItemsRequested($event)"
             itemDeleteAnimation="Fade" [listViewLayout]="layout">
    <template tkListItemTemplate let-post="item" let-index="index">
        <!--- data goes here -->
    </template>
    <template tkListViewHeader>
      <Label text="next page" [nsRouterLink]="['/next-page']"></Label>
    </template>
</RadListView>
```

In NextPage component when user clicks on back button ActionItem I am redirecting page to posts page(i.e RadListView page) like below

```
goBack(){
        this.routerExtensions.backToPreviousPage();
    }
```

It working fine when 'loadOnDemandMode' not triggered i.e with initial items loaded in list.
I am getting below error when list refreshes with loadOnDemandMode and clicks on next page and back from that page using backToPreviousPage()

```
Feb  1 20:28:36  MacBook-Pro tingrnsapp[39294]: file:///app/tns_modules/ui/core/view-common.js:748:22: JS ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'child.onLoaded')
Feb  1 20:28:36  MacBook-Pro SpringBoard[5176]: [KeyboardArbiter] HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
Feb  1 20:28:36  MacBook-Pro com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.0E8C3B6B-C97F-44B9-8286-697D21C32991.launchd_sim[5159] (UIKitApplication:org.tingr.teacher.prod[0x39cb][39294]): Service exited due to Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: Try to wrap your RadListView in a container element for exmaple `<GridLayout rows="*" cols="*"></GridLayout>`

Comment: Hi  @Nick Iliev tried as mentioned but not working